# Buildfire: How to integrate api,ai to Buildfire plugin

Tags: javascript, json, heroku, plugins, dialogflow-es

I built a chatbot based on API.ai and I'v integrate it with Heroku and Facebook messenger and it is working well. Now, I would like to to integrate this chatbot to Buildfire.com in order to publish it as IPhone and Android apps.

Can someone help me with this case please?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).  Also, be sure to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

So you can do this by creating a custom BuildFire plugin. To get more information about how to do this click here
https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki

Its pretty simple. Using the same Javascript, HTML and CSS that you used for your web application you should be able to migrate that into a BuildFire plugin.

There are many video tutorials on this here
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IZcvBZT-zjY&list=PLnq_waykAGlgsERwxHmGNokE6WIeVeH0I

Hope this helps